# Types in the LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

How does the LLVM backend handle types (i32, i32*, ...) from intermediate representation?

For example:

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
    %2 = alloca i32, align 4
    %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
    %4 = add nsw i32 %3, 54
    store i32 %4, i32* %2, align 4
    ret i32 0
}
```

What is the benefit of the types in the example?

Answer (score 3):

From [LLVMs](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#type-system) documentation:

> The LLVM type system is one of the most important features of the intermediate representation. Being typed enables a number of optimizations to be performed on the intermediate representation directly, without having to do extra analyses on the side before the transformation. A strong type system makes it easier to read the generated code and enables novel analyses and transformations that are not feasible to perform on normal three address code representations.

Comment: Unfortunately the docs don't give an example of an optimisation which would be tricky with an un-typed IR.